# How to use a function to evaluate ngClass conditional statement in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

so within my `*ngfFor` loop I have this

```
[ngClass]="{'first':isStartDate(event,day)}"
```

where `isStartDate` is a function in my component.

error thrown is

> "Unexpected token : "

Is it possible to to use a function here?

Comment: [class.first]="ifStartDate(event,day)"

Comment: your issue resolve or not ? @user3057416

Answer (score 3):

ifStartDate function is return only boolean value

```
[class.first]="ifStartDate(event,day)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also give dynamic class as below:

```
[ngClass]="ifStartDate(event,day) ? 'first' : ''"
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to implement it:

```
<div [ngClass]="ifStartDate(event,day)">
</div>

ifStartDate(event, day) {
    let cssClasses;

    if(some condition) {  
      cssClasses = {
       'first': true
      } 
    } else {  
      cssClasses = {
       'second': true,
       'third': true 
      } 
    }

    return cssClasses;
}
```

**In this way you can also apply multiple classes over div based on some condition.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression in `ngClass`:

```
[ngClass]="'{first:'+ifStartDate(event,day)+'}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely use function in `ngClass`

```
[ngClass]="{first: isStartDate(event,day)}"
```